# three.js selecting children of Object3D using raycaster.intersectObject

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, three.js, parent-child

I am trying to make a series of cubes that can be clicked to highlight them. This will enable me to change their color or add a texture or manipulate them in some way. I have looked through the source code of all the interactive examples at https://threejs.org/examples/ and it appears that each example uses a slightly different way of creating and selecting objects in the scene. I am not used to using javascript though, so maybe I'm missing something simple.

I create an Object3D class named blocks to store all of the cubes

```
blocks = new THREE.Object3D()
```

I am using a for loop to create a 9 x 9 array of cubes starting at (0,0,0) coordinates with a slight gap between them, and add() them to blocks and add() blocks to the scene. example: (cube size 2,2,2)

```
   function stack(mx,my,mz){
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
          line(mx,my,mz);
          mz += 3;
        }
    }

    function line(mx,my,mz){
        for (var i = 0;i<9;i++){
          var block = new THREE.Mesh( Geometry, Material);
          block.position.x = mx;
          block.position.y = my;
          block.position.z = mz;

          blocks.add(block);
          mx+=3;
        }
    }
    stack(mx,my,mz) 
    scene.add(blocks)
```

When I run this code, I can see them rendered. I use raycaster to .intersectObjects() which requires an array of objects. This is where I run into the problem of selecting just one object.

```
function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, -( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
    projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);
    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());
    **var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(blocks.children, true);**

    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        intersects[0].object.material.transparent = true;
        other code stuff blah blah blah
    {
```

This will make all children clickable but they have the same .id as the first object created. so if I try to .getObjectById() in order to change something, it doesn't work.

I have tried to generate each element and add them to the scene iteratively instead of creating an object array to hold them and it still has a similar effect. I've tried storing them in a regular array and then using true parameter to recursively search the .intersectObject() array but it selects all of the objects when I click on it.

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(blocks, true);
```

I have considered creating 81 unique variables to hold each element and statically typing an array of 81 variables (desperate option) but I can't find a secure way to dynamically create variable names in the for loop to hold the objects. This way was posted on stackoverflow as a solution to creating different named variables but it doesn't seem to create variables at all.

```
for (var i=0, i<9, i++){
    var window["cube" + i] = new THREE.Mesh( Geometry, Material)
    {
```

Main Question: How can I iteratively create multiple Mesh's (enough that statically typing each variable would be ill-advised) in a controllable way that I can select them and manipulate them individually and not as a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason why you met this problem is you reference same `Material` to build your `Mesh`, you did intersect a single object in `blocks.children`, but when you change some properties of the material others mesh who use the material would change too.

```
function line(mx,my,mz){
    for (var i = 0;i<9;i++){
      material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
      var block = new THREE.Mesh( Geometry, material);
      block.position.x = mx;
      block.position.y = my;
      block.position.z = mz;

      blocks.add(block);
      mx+=3;
    }
}
```

it works for me.